In Scilab, the 'continue' statement is not working as detailed in the documents
I have a try and catch block inside 2 for loops in Scilab:
for r = 1:rows
    for c = 1:columns
        try
            FBJ = acosd((BF^2 + BJ^2 - FJ^2)/(2*BF*BJ));
        catch
            continue
        end
        alfa_FB = alfa_JB + FBJ;
    end
end


The continue statement should NOT compute the below line of code but it keeps trying to do so. I know this because I'm getting an undefined variable error.
alfa_FB = alfa_JB + FBJ;

I think the continue statement either has stopped working or it doesn't work when placed inside try/catch blocks.
Please try the code before you comment.
I want to skip the error and move on to the next iteration. I simply want the damn continue statement to work.
Any ideas?

You could always move the alfa_FB assignment inside the try catch block. My instinct is that if the input values are what I think they might be then the value that acosd is presented with will only ever be outside the range -1 to 1 due to rounding errors. In that case you are much better off computing the raw value checking its magnitude for being  less than of equal to 1 and if it is just outside that range force it to 1 before calling acosd. If it way out then fault it. try catch is a lazy way to do things. You should properly analyse how and why code could fail.

Thanks for your comment. The issue is, I’m creating a program that allows the user to input a matrix of coordinate positions for a machine. The program needs to then make over 20 calculations to determine if the position is achievable or not. Mathematically, if one of the equations has no solution, then that position is not achievable and so I want that position to be skipped. So I have no interest in determining why the value fell out of the range because I know the geometry is invalid.

However, you’ve said that I can put the remaining statements in the try block. That may just work for my purposes but it doesn’t seem right to jam so many equations into a try block.
I’m still angry that ‘continue’ simply doesn’t work as the docs say it does.

1 possible answer:
There’s a 5 year old regression bug. Continue statements just don’t work in try blocks.
As per:
https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/issues/15732
